# Accessing webserver on AWS ec2 (Ubuntu)

Tags: amazon-ec2, firewall, ubuntu-18.04

I am running a webserver on an Ubuntu ec2 instance. The service accepts http connections over port 8080.

The next step is to allow the service to be e accessible using public_DNS:8080. I've modified the security group to accept all incoming traffic on 8080. However, I get connection refused when I try it on my browser. I am guessing it is something to do with the Ubuntu firewall.

I have very little idea about it. Any suggestions on how I can proceed to resolve this?

Comment: If you did not configure it explicitly, and if you used the default official ami with ubuntu then there won't be firewall configured. Have you confirmed you actually listen something on :8080? What IP is it bound to? What exactly do you have in your SG?

Comment: Here is the result of 

$ netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN:

tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          :::*                    LISTEN      10917/java

Comment: Also, the sg is configured to accept all traffic on all port ranges for both inbound and outbound

Comment: I got it done! I changed the listening interface on the application and that solved it! Thanks